# I want to convert my function to a function without recursion in C#

Tags: c#, logic

I created a program to solve sudoku grid, but I have a recursive function and I would like eliminate that recursion.

This is my function in C#:

```
static bool Résoudre()
{
    for (int ligne = 0; ligne < 16; ligne++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 16; col++)
        {
            if (grille[ligne, col] == 0)
            {
                for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
                {
                    if (Vérification(ligne, col, num))
                    {
                        grille[ligne, col] = num;

                        if (Résoudre())
                            return true;

                        grille[ligne, col] = 0;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Eliminating recursion in a function is a standard thing to do - an explicit stack is the most common method, or tail recursion elimination (not applicable here). What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: In general it's a good idea to provide all the relevant code (in this case the definition of Resoudre and grille). Are you aiming to improve performance by removing recursion or is this a requirement for a homework assignment or something?

Comment: it's a requirement for homework, I tried to use a stack but without success

Answer (score -1):

Think about what this is actually doing;

```cs
if (Résoudre())
    return true;
```

The function call operation will push a return address onto the stack. When the method starts, it will allocate new space on the stack for local variables. The return statement will unwind the stack and jump back to the return address.

So how could you emulate this?

Define a struct to represent your local variables and the return address. Though since you only have one function call, this is redundant. Allocate an array of those structures, based on the maximum stack depth. Use goto's to jump to the start of the function, or resume on "return".

In your case, instead of `return false` you resume the previous iteration. But since any `return true` will cause all iterations to unwind, you can skip that and return from the method directly.

```cs
struct variables {
    int ligne;
    int col;
    int num;
}

static bool Résoudre(){
    Span<variables> stack = stackalloc variables[16*16];
    var depth = 0;

    start:
    for(stack[depth].ligne = 0; ...
        ...
                grille[stack[depth].ligne, stack[depth].col] = stack[depth].num;
                // emulate recursive call;
                depth++;
                goto start;

                resume:

                grille[stack[depth].ligne, stack[depth].col] = 0;
        ...

        // emulate return false;
        if (depth == 0)
            return false;
        depth--;
        goto resume;
        ...
    }

    return true;
}
```

There is another optimisation available to you. Since your method is scanning for empty space and filling it. You don't need to restart from the beginning on every iteration.